# Raspberry pi how to install java in debian wheezy

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

I am trying to install JDK 1.8.0 in my debian Raspberry Pi. I downloaded the tar ball and extracted the file in `/opt/java`. I then included the path in `/etc/profile`. After that installed Netbeans 7.4 on the Raspberry Pi and tried to build a JavaFX application from Netbeans. The error shown then is "*JavaFX run time jar is not found*"

I checked the JDK 1.8.0 folder and compared it with the JDK 1.8.0 folder in my windows and I found out that many of JavaFX files are missing in my JDK 1.8.0 folder on raspberry pi.

Can any one suggest how to install JDK 1.8.0 and build a JavaFX application in raspberry pi?

Comment: can we install jdk1.8.0 for linux in arm linux ????

Comment: I have jdk 1.8 running fine in my raspberry. However, don't know if javafx is supported there.

Comment: can run jar build from windows in raspberry pi with jdk1.8.0  .... but cant build a javafx application ..

Answer (score 0):

The OpenJDK has an official doc for running [JavaFX on the  raspberry PI.](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/OpenJFX+on+the+Raspberry+Pi)

Have you gone through it already ?

As far as I know the JavaFX binaries are in the tar.gz file that you can [download](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) from the jdk8 website.

Comment: no .. i had downloaded it 6 times from the above mentioned link ... it is 83.60 mb file for Linux ARMv6/7 VFP, HardFP ABI  ...

Comment: but it is not containing many files to deploy a javafx application from raspberry pi.. i dont know why it is happened